# Html regex pattern: [\d\s-]{3} works but [\d-\s]{3} doesn't. Why?

Tags: html, regex, html-input

Codepen example:
https://codepen.io/Trost/pen/KXBRbY
Try putting 1 symbol in both fields.
I can't get what's wrong. If I test these regex in https://regex101.com, they appear to be identical.

```
<form>
  Works: <input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[\d\s-]{3}" title="-23" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<form>
  Bug: <input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[\d-\s]{3}" title="- 3" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `-` has special meaning when used in the middle of a `[]` character class. But with `\d` and `\s` around it, it doesn't really make much sense so it can fail depending on the implementation. In `[\d\s-]` however it is at the end of the class, which means it has no special meaning.

Comment: It is because you test with PCRE option at regex101.com and in the HTML5 pattern it is parsed as an ES6 regex with `u` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real root cause here is that the regex `[\d-\s]` is used in the `pattern` HTML5 attribute, and in the latest versions of Chrome and FireFox is compiled as an ES2015-compatible regex with the `u` modifier. The consequence is that there are **much stricter escaping rules** for the Unicode regex patterns.

[image]

What it means is whenever a char cannot be parsed unambiguously, it is an error. When a char is escaped, but does not need escaping, it is again an error.

The chars that you may escape in the character class inside a `u` based regex are `+`, `$`, `^`, `*`, `(`, `)`, `|`, `\`, `[`, `]`, `.`, `?`, `-`, `{`, `}` (see [this source](http://2ality.com/2015/07/regexp-es6.html#regular-expressions)). If the `-` is at the start/end of the character class, it still can go unescaped, as it can only be parsed as a literal hyphen there.

In between two shorthand character classes, an unescaped `-` will produce an error because it is treated as a user error.

So, either place a hyphen at the start/end (it is always the best option), or escape it inside the character class (and never escape it outside of the character class).

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that "-" is used for defining symbol ranges. And the fact that it worked in regex101.com confused me even further.  
TIL: You can test regex in JS console using /regex/.test("teststring");

Comment: @Trost [Regex101 has its own bugs, too.](https://regex101.com/r/cvFxtw/1)

Answer (score 1):

You define two different things:

- `[a-z]` is a definition of a range - all characters from `a` to `z`.
- `[az-]` is a definition of a set of three elements - `a`, `z` and
  `-`.