# What char to escape for html input pattern???,

Tags: regex, html

I can't for the life of me find a list of chars to escape. So first question, where can I find a list of chars to escape for **HTML5 input pattern**.
Because, and this is my 2nd question, I cannot find a way for this pattern to work

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_\-!\?\#]{6,}"
```

What do I need to escape. Please full list if you can.

Comment: Use `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_!?#-]{6,}"`. Only `-` can be escaped here.

Comment: `[\w!?#-]{6,}`?

Comment: You can find all the chars you may need to escape in a character class in the [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46719117/3832970).